# Are questions and answers still accessible if private beta fails to enter into public beta?

Tags: discussion, beta

The questions and answers on this site have become sufficiently valuable to cause me to (embarrassingly) copy and paste them into files on my local machine just in case the private beta fails to enter public beta. Is there any need for me to do that? Does the content in private beta get destroyed if this fails to reach public beta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When sites get closed down we provide a data dump of all questions and answers in the Area 51 proposal. See an example [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106367/augur).